# Motion security

Tags: motion, security

I installed motion by apt and run as the default configuration. I open `http://raspberrypi:8080` and I can see the camera's output. I will use it over the internet and I'm worried about the security of that. I want to change all connections to https which is the least security that I can configure. How can I make all connection to https? I didn't find anything in the config file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It's simple. There is some TLS feature for the web interface and also for the stream port.

---

### Generate your certificate files:

```
apt-get install openssl

openssl genrsa -out /etc/motion/motion.key 4096
openssl req -new -key /etc/motion/motion.key -out /etc/motion/motion.crt
```

Now, you have created key and certificate file for the motion config file.

---

### Motion config:

Add these lines to the `/etc/motion/motion.conf`:

```
stream_tls on
webcontrol_tls on
webcontrol_key /etc/motion/motion.key
webcontrol_cert /etc/motion/motion.crt
```

Restart the motion service by `service motion restart` and then open `https://raspberrypi:8080` on a host.

---

Related links:

[Motion configuration file manual](https://motion-project.github.io/4.2.2/motion_config.html#webcontrol_tls)
[SSL Certificate Signing with CAcert for Raspberry Pi, Ubuntu & Debian](https://samhobbs.co.uk/2014/04/ssl-certificate-signing-cacert-raspberry-pi-ubuntu-debian)
[Self-Signed_Certificate](https://wiki.debian.org/Self-Signed_Certificate)