# Stream raspberry pi camera on web page

Tags: camera, pi-4

I realized that i can plug my web camera to raspberry pi. now i'm looking for a way to stream it on a web page. also i want to get streams over internet.
are them possible? how can i install it? thanks.

Comment: https://www.linux-projects.org/uv4l/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the `motion` package on your Raspbian Buster to stream the camera's frames. Simply install it by `apt-get install motion`.
After the installation, try to configure it by changing values on `/etc/motion/motion.conf`. If you just want to stream the frames without any feature else, try these lines there:

```
stream_localhost off
stream_port 8081
daemon on
#webcam_localhost on
#webcam_port 8080
```

Then, run `motion` on the terminal and open up this web page address on the other motions web browser:

```
http://raspberrypi:8081
```

You'll see a page with the raspberry pis camera frames/streams. If you are concerned about the security of motion, check [this link](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/107868/motion-security/107872#107872) out. Also, more configuration options are here in [this link](https://motion-project.github.io/motion_config.html).

Comment: can i open the web page stream on localhost after adding `stream_localhost off`?

Comment: Yes, it's just for disabling vice versa host to localhost. If it's `on` you can open the web page by localhost and when it's `off`, all host (include localhost) can open it up.

Answer (score 2):

I use MotionEyeOS but if you also want to use your pi for other stuff you can just install MotionEye